# How to assign an integer array declared inside a structure directly?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, structure

```
struct data
{
    char name;
    int conn[3];
};

typedef struct data unit;
typedef unit *link;

int main()
{
    int i;
    link p[100];
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {
        p[i]=(link)malloc(sizeof(unit));
        p[i]->name='h';
        p[i]->conn[]=(int*){"1","1","1"};   **// assignment error**
    }
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",p[i]->name,p[i]->conn[0],p[i]->conn[1],p[i]->conn[2]); 
    }
    getch();
}
```

As structures does not support initialization so, is there any way to assign this type of arrays declared inside a structure in a single line of code without using mem allocation functions and all for the sake of simplicity?
Please stick to the code.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you declare `conn[2]` but you try to access `conn[2]` which if off by one. This isn't going to end well...

Comment: oops editing...

Comment: @M.M I forgot about structure assignment. Would you make an answer with explanation out of this?

Comment: You can't assign to arrays directly.  You can assign whole structures even if the structure contains arrays, but you can't assign arrays as arrays.

Comment: BTW: both lines `for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)` are also off by one. It should be: `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)`

Answer (score 5):

After the malloc line you can write:

```
*p[i] = (struct data){'h', {1, 1, 1}};
```

This uses structure assignment with a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) as the source.

BTW I would recommend doing the malloc line this way: `p[i] = malloc(sizeof *p[i]);`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1505939) for explanation.

Comment: @RahulKumar note the `*` in M.M 's version, it is missing in yours and it is important.

Comment: Yeah! i missed in excitement